# Creating two objects of a class in another class in Java

Tags: java, class, constructor

I'm trying to create two objects of a Silo class in a `SiloManager` class, so that I can access both objects' methods. But I can't seem to make the `SiloManager` constructor work, nor to instance the classes properly. (I'm a beginner in java). Here's my code:

```
public class GrainSiloManager {

    public GrainSilo silo1 = new GrainSilo(100);
    public GrainSilo silo2 = new GrainSilo(50);


    public GrainSiloManager(GrainSilo silo1, GrainSilo silo2) {
        this.silo1 = silo1;
        this.silo2 = silo2;
    }

    private void showStatus() {
        System.out.println("The current grain in silo1 is: " + silo1.getGrain());
        System.out.println("The current grain in silo2 is: " + silo2.getGrain());
    }

}
```

As I say i'm a beginnger so go easy heh, thanks for any help.

Comment: Looks ok, but which objects do you want? You are instantiating silo1 and silo2 as class-variables, but don't use them since you take the arguments from the constructor. Also, if GrainSilo is not working we need to see the code from that class.

Comment: You need to include the code for GrainSilo.

Comment: You are initializing `silo1` and `silo2` as new `GainSilo` instances, but then redefining them in the constructor.  Which one is the one you actually want to use?

Answer (score 4):

```
public GrainSilo silo1 = new GrainSilo(100);
public GrainSilo silo2 = new GrainSilo(50);


public GrainSiloManager(GrainSilo silo1, GrainSilo silo2) {
    this.silo1 = silo1;
    this.silo2 = silo2;
}
```

This will get compiled as:

```
public GrainSilo silo1;
public GrainSilo silo2;


public GrainSiloManager(GrainSilo silo1, GrainSilo silo2) {
    this.silo1 = new GrainSilo(100);
    this.silo2 = new GrainSilo(50);
    this.silo1 = silo1;
    this.silo2 = silo2;
}
```

which as you can see makes little to no sense. You're overwriting the object that you make, with the objects passed into the constructor.

Comment: Very good explanation to the poster. I've never actually thought about instantiating instance variables like that being equivalent to instantiating them in the constructor first. Is that how it gets compiled in reality?

Comment: @John http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html "The Java compiler copies initializer blocks into every constructor.". The biggest thing to know it that, field initializers will always happen before the constructor. If this behaviour wasn't well defined, then you would get different silo objects here depending on the compiler

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor is going to replace the "public!" silo1 and silo2 objects with whatever is passed in. You could change your constructor like this

```
 public GrainSiloManager() {
    super();
 }
```

or the even shorter (but equivalent)

```
 public GrainSiloManager() {
 }
```

And then call it like this

```
 new GrainSiloManager().showStatus();
```

or you can use your existing approach (which will replace the GrainSoloManager.silo1 and GrainSoloManager.silo2 in your constructor)

```
 GrainSilo silo1 = new GrainSilo(100);
 GrainSilo silo2 = new GrainSilo(50);
 new GrainSiloManager(silo1, silo2).showStatus();
```

Comment: With the caveat that there's no reason to call super in the ctor for the class as defined above.

Comment: @Dave-Newton with the caveat that there's no reason to explicitly place that call to super because Java will do it for us it anyway (if we omit it)!